# What Firefox Driver does Selenium use?

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium, junit

I’m trying to use Selenium WebDriver with Eclipse and JUnit and a Firefox browser to do a series of Link tests. The trouble I’m having is the Firefox browser is opening some links in a new Window. Note: these are not Alerts. 
I have the browser set to open all links in the same window, and if I navigate to the chosen links manually it does what it’s supposed to do. These are the settings of the default browser at present.

```
browser.link.open_newwindow;                                 1
browser.link.open_newwindow.disabled_in_fullscreen;          true
browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external:               1
browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction;                     2
```

When I run the same thing in Eclipse as a JUnit test from Eclipse the link opens up in a new window!
I commented out `driver.close()` and checked the browser that Eclipse was using and all the settings are different. There is even another setting that isn’t in my browser.

```
browser.link.open_newwindow;                                  2
browser.link.open_newwindow.disabled_in_fullscreen;           false
browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external:               -1
browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction;                      2
browser.link.open_external                                    2
```

If I use a profile or force it to use the default profile it the browser it uses has these settings.

```
browser.link.open_newwindow;                                  2
browser.link.open_newwindow.disabled_in_fullscreen;           true
browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external:                1
browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction;                      2
browser.link.open_external                                    2
```

From reading previous posts I was of the understanding that Eclipse/Selenium/JUnit would use the default browser installed on my PC. Or at least the default browser profile

My Code:

```
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.junit.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

    public class Pro2 {
      private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;
      private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
        // driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "https://www.google.ie/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

My questions are:

- Is it using a different driver(or driver profile)?
- If so how do I set the config settings so that all links open in the current window?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify firefox profile before you use it in your tests by calling `SetPreference` method of the `FirefoxProfile` class:

```
ffprofile.SetPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow", "1");
```

Comment: I tried that but it gave me this error: java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Preference browser.link.open_newwindow may not be overridden

Comment: Which error? Feel free to add the error to your post if it doesn't fit in a comment.

Comment: java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Preference browser.link.open_newwindow may not be overridden frozen value=2, requested value=1